# CSS-grid auto-flow: dense not working

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, css-grid

**You can think of this as we upload multiple pictures (may be of different dimensions) on Facebook and they display them nicely, in their newsfeed.**

I have a container `.wrapper` it contains a `CSS-grid` layout box having class `.card-img-grid`. It can have a maximum for 4 images, but they will be of different  `width` and `height`, i.e., some will have a square shape, some will be long in either direction(vertically or horizontally). Totally depends on how a user has uploaded.

My problem is due to the difference in the size of images grid, is creating the white gaps, which is ruining my complete UX. Please help me, how can I fix that or there is another way to achieve **Facebook** type layout for multiple images?

I want the grid to adjust on its own according to the images. Also, I cannot use
`grid-column: span 2;grid-row: span 2;` like properties, becoz I don't know abt how big or small images are. Working codepen [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBJxBo)

**My Angular Template**

```
<div class="card-img-grid">
  // Loop will be displaying only 4 images, but can have different size
  <ng-container *ngFor="let img of feed.images | slice: 0 : 4">
     <div class="img-grid-item">
       <img class="w-100" [src]="img.url"> // .w-100 sets width: 100%
      </div>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.card-img-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  margin: 14px 0 5px;
}
.card-img-grid .img-grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image: My layout]

Comment: Guess fr causing some issue

Comment: @Developer suggestions please?

Comment: I am also trying from my end can you go flex method?

Comment: Yeah no problem... can you try to do that in the codepen and save or post your working answer?

Comment: Not for nothing but I think FB maintains scale and then crops the preview. So essentially you'll never get a rectangle to fit neatly inside a grid that is all squares and vice versa, you'll never get a square to fit neatly in a grid of rectangles. I would at least consider the possibility that this isn't a layout issue but more of an image preview issue.

Comment: @Mark Carpenter Jr can't u suggest anything to fix tht

Comment: I just did scale the image up slightly and crop.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple CSS can accomplish this depending on your requirements.

```
#container {
   column-count:4;
   column-gap: 0;  

   .img-card {
     width:100%;
   }
}
```

**Example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-image-cols

Comment: Using your method, images are comming properly but still not what I wanted... thnx anyways